# Parse XSD results from webservice

Tags: php, xml, xsd, simplexml

How can I parse, iterate, or convert to array the following result?

This is the exact result as received via SOAP.
And eventually I will need to get the items into an array.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/PriceListDS.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/PriceListDS.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="PriceListDS" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/PriceListDS.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="PriceListDS" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="PriceList">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="itemcode">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="itemname" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="OrigPrice" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="Multiple" msdata:ReadOnly="true" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="vat" msdata:ReadOnly="true" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:PriceList"/>
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:itemcode"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[*Note that below fragment had been grouped together with XSD above.  Separated for clarity.*]

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <PriceListDS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/PriceListDS.xsd">
    <PriceList diffgr:id="PriceList1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <itemcode>
.........
```

I'm using PHP to get the response

```
try{   
  $options = array( 
    'trace'      =>1,
    'encoding'   => 'UTF-8',         
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
   );

   $client = new SoapClient($url, $options );

$response = $client->GetPrice($request);
```

The result is actually an object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetPriceResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => xsd_result
         )
)
```

Tried using SimpleXML

```
$xml_doc = simplexml_load_string($response->GetPriceResult->any);
```

But I'm getting `Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error`

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if your question provided (1) the language you wish to use to process the XML, (2) what you've tried so far, and (3) an explanation as to why you're receiving an XSD ("*this is the exact result as received via soap*") rather than a document instance, if this is even intentional.

Comment: Sorry , edited the question